# Listening to waveforms

Tags: matlab

In Matlab I want to hear the differences between what two waveforms sound like. What is the function used to listen to audio in Matlab? For example I have two waveforms from a file

```
wav1 = wavread('audio1.wav');
wav2 = wavread('audio2.wav');
```

how am I able to play these waveforms over my speakers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Matlab command to play a waveform is the sound command.  it is used like so:

```
sound(wav1,F1);
sound(wav2,F2);
```

where F1 and F2 are the frequency used in playback. you can obtain the frequency from an audio file using your same wavread command thusly:

```
[wav1,F1,Nbits1] = wavread('audio1.wav');
```

where Nbits1 is the number of data points in the audio file.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [sound](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sound.html) and [soundsc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/soundsc.html) functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `sound(wav1, 22050)`. 
Of course, if you need higher sample rate, you can always change it.
You could use just `sound(wav1)` - however, you should always specify sample rate
in order to make sure you hear the waveform properly.